# Catching exceptions based on their abstract base class

Tags: python, exception, abstract-base-class

Suppose I've got an exception class with an abstract base class, something like this:

```
class MyExceptions(BaseExeption, metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
    pass

class ProperSubclass(MyExceptions):
    pass

MyExceptions.register(ValueError)
```

It appears that I can catch `ProperSubclass` by `MyExceptions`, but not `ValueError`:

```
try:
    raise ProperSubclass()
except MyExceptions:
    print('As expected, control comes here...')
except:
    print('...and not here.')

try:
    raise ValueError()
except MyExceptions:
    print('Control does not come here...')
except ValueError:
    print('...but unexpectedly comes here.')
```

So my question is, should I be able to catch built-in exceptions by their abstract base class? If so, how? And if not, what are the rules?

I guess another way of asking this is: do except clauses properly use isinstance()/issubclass() for matching, and if not (as appears to be the case) what *do* they use? Perhaps there are some shady shortcuts down in the C implementation.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/compound_stmts.html#try) says:

> An object is compatible with an exception if it is the class or a base class of the exception object or a tuple containing an item compatible with the exception.

Unfortunately, this doesn't say whether virtual base classes should be considered, unlike the language for e.g. [issubclass](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#issubclass):

> Return true if *class* is a subclass (direct, indirect or *virtual*) of *classinfo*. [...]

The language on overriding [instance and subclass checks](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-instance-and-subclass-checks) doesn't help much either:

> The following methods are used to override the default behavior of the `isinstance()` and `issubclass()` built-in functions. [...]

In fact, as you have suspected, the CPython implementation (for Python 3) bypasses subclass checks, calling `PyType_IsSubtype` directly:

http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.4/Python/errors.c#l167

```
PyErr_GivenExceptionMatches(PyObject *err, PyObject *exc)
{
    ...
        /* PyObject_IsSubclass() can recurse and therefore is
           not safe (see test_bad_getattr in test.pickletester). */
        res = PyType_IsSubtype((PyTypeObject *)err, (PyTypeObject *)exc);
```

For reference, the CPython implementation of issubclass, [PyObject_IsSubclass](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.4/Objects/abstract.c#l2585), calls `__subclasscheck__` before falling back to `PyType_IsSubtype`.

So there is a good reason for this behavior; exception handling needs to be non-recursive, so it isn't safe for it to call back up into Python code.  Note that the [Python 2.7 version](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Python/errors.c#l84) accepts the risk of overflow and does call `PyObject_IsSubclass`.  There is a [proposal to relax this restriction](https://bugs.python.org/issue12029) in Python 3, but although a patch has been written it hasn't yet been accepted.  Otherwise, it would be a good idea for the documentation to clarify that `except` checks are non-virtual.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. Thanks for tracking that down.

Comment: Note that if you use Python2.7, `PyErr_GivenExceptionMatches` actually does call `PyObject_IsSubclass`, and it will work.

Comment: For some more in-depth discussion, also see https://bugs.python.org/issue12029 where Georg Brandl came up with a draft proposal for lifting this restriction by carefully manipulating the exception state around the `PyObject_IsSubclass` call.